# Subscript out of range when using Userform input workbook as reference

Tags: excel, vba

I have put together a userform for the user to select an open workbook - ideally would like to have this integrated with a script so that the script runs in reference to the workbook chosen. 
However an out of range error presents when running the script:

```
Private Sub Go_Click()

 If ComboBox1.ListIndex = -1 Then
        MsgBox "Please select a workbook name and try again"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim wb As Workbook, copytest As Range, pastetest As Range

    Set wb = Workbooks(ComboBox1.List(ComboBox1.ListIndex))


   Set copytest = wb.Worksheets(2).Columns(6)
   Set pastetest = Workbooks("VBA Workbook.xlsx").Worksheets(1).Columns(1)
   copytest.Copy Destination:=pastetest

        '~~> Do what you want

Debug.Print

End Sub
```

Combo box:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()


    Dim wkb As Workbook
    Me.Label1.Caption = "Please select the relevant workbook"
    With Me.ComboBox1
        '~~> Loop thorugh all open workbooks and add
        '~~> their name to the Combobox
        For Each wkb In Application.Workbooks
            .AddItem wkb.Name
        Next wkb
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Where is the error?

Comment: Please show how you populate the combobox. Is it multi-column? The reason for the out of range is that the result of `Combobox1.List(Combobox1.ListIndex)` is not something that can be resolved to an open workbook.

Comment: Added in original post :)

Answer (score 0):

`.ListIndex` returns a number that goes from 0 to ListCount - 1 (think of it as a Zero based array). So when you pass 0 for the 1st item (if that is what is selected) then Workbooks(0) will fail with the out of range error. Anything else will be off by one item in the list and the last one will never be able to be used.

Adjust your code accordingly (i.e. add 1 to `.ListIndex`). Hint: that is why -1 means nothing in the combobox is selected.

Generally, you would want to check if `wb` is not nothing. To be able to do that you'd wrap the assignment line `wb = Workbooks(ComboBox1.List(ComboBox1.ListIndex))` with `On Error Resume Next`/`On Error GoTo 0`. Which will suspend the error that you got originally and let your code to continue so you can check `If Not wb Is Nothing Then` and proceed accordingly.

Having said all of that I would suggest you use meaningful names instead of `Combobox1`. Also, you didn't provide how you `.Show` your user form. Make sure that you are not using the default instance, and give your user form a meaningful name and the object that you set it to also to have a meaningful name. You will thank yourself later.

Comment: Interesting. I added 1 and changed it to   `(ComboBox1.ListIndex) + 1)), it is now giving a different error of "Could not get the list property. Invalid property array index" - In my research this error can mean the array is empty, but what exactly does that mean? Error highlights the exact same line

Comment: Instead of hiding the result of `ComboBox1.List(ComboBox1.ListIndex)` within the call to workbooks declare a variable `As Variant` to hold that result; put in a breakpoint at that assignment and see what that variable holds and what type it is. `Dim whatIsIt As Variant whatIsIt=ComboBox1.List(ComboBox1.ListIndex)`

Comment: Seems there is a type mismatch...


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9b4ZE.png

Comment: You are using `Set` when you shouldn't. My suggestion is to have a *different* variable declared and see what `ComboBox1.List(ComboBox1.ListIndex)` is actually returning:`Dim myHelperVariable As Variant` and then `myHelperVariable = ComboBox1.List(ComboBox1.ListIndex)`

Comment: Thanks.  There is no longer an error surrounding the combo box.  Can I still use the variable to refer to ranges within it? For example:  ```  wb.worksheets(2).columns("F") ```   -  ```wb``` being the variable we had just defined.  An object required error is returning from that line

Comment: It looks like the way you have wb defined you can use it to reference objects that belong to it (sheets) and the objects that belong to the children (ranges, etc) the way you have it now you would be doing each call to those children (sheets) and the children of sheets inside the for each wb loop. If that is what you are wanting to do, then yes.